# Ordered or not ordered pairs in sample space

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If two integers are selected, at random and without replacement from $\large \{1,2,3,…,99,100\}$, what is the probability that:

1. their sum is even?
2. the integers are consecutive?

**What I've tried**

I assumed that the order of integers in each pair matters, that is, $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ are two different possible outcomes.

Then, there're $\large \dfrac {100!} {(100-2)!} = 9900$ possible outcomes.

Let $\large A$ be the event in the first question. Then $\large |A|=49\cdot50\cdot2=4900$. Consequently, $\large Pr(A)=\dfrac{4900}{9900}=\dfrac{49}{99}$.

The solution manual to my book provides the same answer, though they achieve it in another way. Below is the book's solution to the first question.

$\large S = \{(x,y)|x,y\in \{1,2,3,…,99,100\},x\ne y\}$
$\large A = \{(x,y)|{x,y}\in S, x,y \text{ even}\}\cup \{(x,y)|{x,y}\in S, x,y \text{ odd}\}$

$\large |S|=\dbinom{100}2=4950$

$\large |A|=\dbinom{50}2+\dbinom{50}2=2450$

$\large Pr(A)=\dfrac{2450}{4950}=\dfrac{49}{99}$

Well, I understand that since $x+y=y+x$ we can ignore the order of integers in pairs in this case. But for the second question (about consecutive numbers) the book defines the event in question as $\large B=\{(x,x+1)|x\in \{1,2,3,…,99\}\}$. Then $\large |B|=99$, and $\large Pr(B)=\dfrac {99}{4950}=\dfrac 1 {50}$.

I know it's $\large \dfrac 1{50}$. **What I don't understand** how is it that the order of integers in pairs is ignored here?

The question is probably dumb, but I'm studying discrete mathematics on my own without any background in the field, so I'm getting stuck from time to time. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Given that you can't choose the same integer twice, it doesn't matter whether you keep track of the order or not.  For things like dice rolls, it matters because, getting an unordered $\{1,2\}$ is twice as probable as getting an unordered $\{1,1\}$ so if you want equal probability (always an advantage for computations) you ought to retain the order.  But here, it doesn't matter.  What's important is to be clear and consistent about what an event is.  If an event is an ordered pair $(a,b)$ then keep it that way throughout.  If unordered, then stick with that.

Comment: To rephrase that:  what matters here is *consistency*.  You can define an event as selecting an ordered pair from the $100\times 99$ possible ordered pairs, or as selecting an unordered pair from the $50\times 99$ possible unordered pairs.  Once you have made that choice, stick with it.  You should see that the related computations are very similar.

Comment: @lulu, Thanks a lot for the remark on consistency and underlying the difference when the order matters and when it doesn’t! That’s something I was rather feeling than understanding. Do I get it right that in the question about consecutive integers I should define the event $\large B =\{(x,x\pm 1)| x \in S\}$ if I compute the size of sample space counting the order of integers in pairs (instead of $\large B=\{(x,x+1)|x\in \{1,2,3,…,99\}\}$ when I choose to ignore the order)?

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more careful.  If you are considering ordered pairs, then consecutive means $(a,b)$ where $a\neq b$ are two distinct  elements of $S=\{1, 2, \cdots, 100\}$ such that $|a-b|=1$.  Writing it the way you do, would appear to be slightly incorrect, as taking $x=1$ would mean that $(1,0)\in B$ which it isn't, and taking $x=100$ would incorrectly put $(100,101)\in B$.

Comment: And, if you are disregarding order, use curly brackets or something to stress that.  When order might be a relevant issue, I personally use $(a,b)$ to refer to an ordered pair, and $\{a,b\}$ to refer to an unordered pair, but it's always good to spell that out to avoid confusion.

Comment: Should have said:  you are absolutely right in worrying about these details. In this case, it happens not to make a great deal of difference, but that's just this particular case.  In other contexts, the difference matters a great deal.

Comment: @lulu, Thank you very much!